# Notepad++ user-defined language window too tall

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

Does anyone know how to resize the user-defined language window to a usable size? Maybe even get a fancy `y-axis` scroll-bar.

I am using `1280*1024` and my potato monitor simply can't even. The bottom is cut off for me.

Is the meaning of life found below this cut-off point which only non-peasants of greater than `1024 px` height can view? It's been days since my last meal or sleep, please send halp.

Notepad++ v6.6.9
[image]

Comment: That's strange. I'm using 1920*1080 and it only takes up 2/3 of my screen height.

Comment: @DavidPostill What version are you using?

Comment: With Notepad++ 6.8.6, the top section is a little bit more compressed, leaving this window at only 798 px high on my system. But even without that compression, I can't see it being any taller than 800px, so I wonder if something else is going on.

Comment: @Berend Not sure, FWIW; my DPI scaling hasn't been touched. It's sitting at 100%. I wonder if a simple version update is going to fix my issue...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Notepad++ 6.7.7

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes it should fix it. I compared your screenshot to my setup more closely, and it seems that also labels (Open, Escape, Close) and their corresponding textboxes are now beside each other, and controls seem to be more closely positioned overall.

Comment: @Berend I updated to 6.8.8 and your findings are correct. The layout has been reworked and the screen is about `798 px` tall. If you would like to convert your comment into an answer then I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of that window was changed somewhere between version 6.6.9 and 6.8.6. In the newer version, some buttons are on the same row instead of below each other, and some labels are moved from the top of their corresponding textboxes to the side. The height of the window is now ~800 px (may vary based on the height of the title bar, which is determined by Windows)

[image: New layout]